# Font not loading in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, font-face, styled-components

This is how I am loading my Font files in reactjs

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import fontUrls from './UberMove-Bold.ttf';
import fontUrls1 from './UberMove-Light.ttf';
import fontUrls2 from './UberMove-Medium.ttf';
import fontUrls3 from './UberMove-Regular.ttf';

const Fonts = styled`
    @font-face {
       font-familty: 'UberMove-Light';
       src: url(${fontUrls1}) format('truetype');
    }`;
```

This throws an error while importing

> Uncaught Error: Cannot create styled-component for component: @font-f .ace{font-familty:'UberMove-Light';src:url(,) format('truetype');}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load the font-face globally and then use it in the components:

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    @import url(${fontUrls1});
    font-family: 'UberMove-Light';
  }
`
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <GlobalStyles />

   //...

  </div>
)
```